How to create an alert for low cpu utilization with uptime
I'm using the custom query below to find VMs with low CPU utilization that have been live for more than 3 days. The query works fine when I execute it, but the alert isn't triggering once I create it. For your information, I'm using Azure Alert-v1 for this alert.
Thanks in advance!


let startdate = ago(7d);
let enddate = now();
let livemachine = Heartbeat 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d) 
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by Computer 
| extend Uptime = AggregatedValue / 1440
| where Uptime > 3 
| project Computer ;
let cpu = InsightsMetrics
    | where Computer in (livemachine)
    | where Namespace contains "Processor" and Name contains "UtilizationPercentage"
    | where TimeGenerated between (startdate .. enddate)
    | project
        startdate,
        enddate,
        TimeGenerated,
        Computer,
        CPUUtilization = Val,
        SubscriptionID = _SubscriptionId,
        ResourceID = _ResourceId
| extend ResourceGroup = split(ResourceID,"/")[4];
cpu | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CPUUtilization)
    by
    bin(TimeGenerated, 7d),
    Computer,
    tostring(ResourceGroup),
    SubscriptionID,
    ResourceID,
    startdate,
    enddate
| join kind=inner (Heartbeat | where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by Computer 
| extend Uptime = AggregatedValue / 1440
| where Uptime > 3 
| project Computer, Uptime ) on Computer
| where AggregatedValue < 0.6
| project
    startdate,
    enddate,
    Computer,
    ResourceGroup,
    round(AggregatedValue, 2),
    SubscriptionID,
    ResourceID,
    TimeGenerated,
    Uptime
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer



Below is the screenshot of alert configuration,




Could you provide the alert configuration screenshot by editing the Question?

@VenkatV, Screenshot added.

Also share the Action Group configuration result.

@VenkatV, I'm not sure why you need action group settings because I'm receiving alerts without integrating with the heartbeat alert. The issue seems to be with the heartbeat itself. Although I can see the results in log analytics, but no alerts have been triggered.

Does anyone know about this issue?
